# SQL traces not shown in junit

Tags: junit, ejb, openjpa

I am working on an application using EJB and OpenJPA. FOr unit testing I use junit.I am running junits using Websphere's embedded container.

```
EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(map containing db properties);
```

In persistence.xml I have set :

```
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE" />
```

I expect SQL traces in console, but no traces are shown.

What else do I need to do for SQL traces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by reading the [knowledge center documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tejb_loggingwjpa.html). From what I recall, you need to use WAS logging rather than OpenJPA p.xml configuration.

Comment: Thanks Rick.Would look into that.